# create lock file to show exact version of npm installed packages

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm

I found different versions in package.json file, than versions returned by executing command-**npm ls depth=0**. I want to create lock file which will show the exact/fixed versions of installed npm packages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NPM as of version 5 automatically creates a `package-lock.json` file for you, which should do what you need.

If you're concerned about using specific package versions, I also recommend modifying your `package.json` to remove the semver caret (`^`, e.g. `^3.0.0` -> `3.0.0`) from each package version number. This ensures that the same version is always downloaded until you explicitly upgrade the package.

Comment: I know that this answers OPs question but you should not teach people how to use things that are no longer useful.

Comment: NPM is the official client to the NPM registry where everyone gets their stuff. It will never cease to be "useful" unless NPMJS.org dies.

Comment: Nope, macs for the past 5 years.

Comment: how can i generate package-lock.json file for npm version-3.10.10

Comment: I don't believe that is possible.

Comment: I upgrade npm to version 5, which created package-lock.json. And this file contains he exact versions for npm installed packages. Thank you @probablyup